# How to document an application or code

Tags: c#, documentation

I have to document a small piece of code (a game), and document the known steps of software engineering (analyze, design, implement, etc...). How can I do it in the code (Visual C#)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use standard documentation markup for C#. [Here is a good article explaining how this is accomplished.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpcommentinganddocs.aspx) Your "analyze & design & implementation" comments could go right above your classes along with sample code. You could then download a tool such as [<strike>NDoc</strike>](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/) or [SandCastle](http://www.codeplex.com/Sandcastle), which will read your assembly documentation markup and generate nice and easily readable documentation.

Comment: NDoc is deprecated now - SandCastle is where its at WRT documentation generation. http://blogs.msdn.com/sandcastle/

Comment: Thanks! I included a link to SandCastle.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [standard documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) markup, generating output using [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://www.codeplex.com/SHFB), which is a great GUI wrapper (and then some) around the [Sandcastle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb608422.aspx) project.